# How to require provider version constraints in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

When running `terraform init` I want to require that all providers being used explicitly specify version constraints. For example running `terraform init` against the following code:

```
resource "random_string" "suffix" {
  length  = 8
}
```

downloads the latest random provider.

I want to error instead if a stanza such as

```
provider "random" {
    version = "= 2.2.1"
}
```

stanza is not defined. Is this possible?

Comment: How would you envision checking for these?

Comment: I was expecting some `init` flag, e.g. `terraform init --require-providers` would fail if a provider is used by not explicitly defined - there does not seem to be anything though

Comment: Software for Terraform code compliance like this: https://www.hashicorp.com/sentinel/

Answer (score 0):

Not with Terraform. It is a good little script to check this. Maybe a git commit hook. Or a resource for your configuration which runs an external python script

```py
from pathlib import Path
import re

p = Path()
for x in p.glob('*.tf'):
    contents = x.read_text()
    if re.match('^terraform[ \t]*{', contents):
        lines = contents.split('\n')
        line_num = 0
        while not re.match('^terraform[ \t]*{', lines[line_num]):
           line_num += 1
        line_num += 1
        while not re.match('^[ \t]*required_providers[ \t]*{', lines[line_num]):
           line_num += 1
        line_num += 1
        source_count = 0
        version_count = 0
        while not re.match('^}', lines[line_num]):
           if re.match('^[ \t]*source[ \t]*=', lines[line_num]):
              source_count += 1
           elif re.match('^[ \t]*version[ \t]*=', lines[line_num]):
              version_count += 1
           line_num += 1
        if source_count > version_count:
           print(f'Error, missing version statement around line {line_num}')
        break
```

Of course, some assumptions are made about your formatting.